# error `child.hasSize': is not true and constrained box not working

Tags: flutter

There was an error `child.hasSize': is not true. widget causing error tabbarview` then I `constrained` it to have size as I thought `textboxes` causing the `error`. But now the `constrained box` also shows it's `not constrained`. What's this and how to fix it?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
onlineStatus = true;  
return ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200, maxWidth:200),
    child: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100, maxWidth: 100),
                child: OnlineIndicator()),
            SizedBox(height: 7),
            ToolSetButton(
                svgPicPath: svgStakPath,
                
                width: 35,
                height: 35,
                function: testFunc),
            SizedBox(height: 11),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through my own problem and found a solution. If you have widgets that includes textboxes etc and if you wanna place the widget inside rows, you need to wrap it around with `sizedbox, expanded, flexible` etc and mention a width.

Answer (score 0):

it would be better if you share the `TabBar`. Here is the concept I get from this `code` and errors.

From the top level `ConstrainedBox` of `Column` we promised that this column widget will take `maxHeight: 200`, and if you our **ui gets less than 200, it will create overflow** (when column children size>=200)

let's check our `Column inside ConstrainedBox`.
as we promised here to give `maxHeight: 100` just for `Container` and therefore it will take 100 .

**let us check the children height**

- Container = 100
- sizedbox  =  10
- Container =  35
- SizedBox  =  11

**So column will take minimum=155 as height** and this widget `parent` gets less than `156` height, it will create bottomOverflow.

**Image with 156 height**

[image: image1]

**Image while height< 156**

[image]